# Stemming for Polish language using Google App Engine Python Search Api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search, stemming, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to use Python Search Api in Google App Engine to search through set of Polish documents and I found, that stemming feature is not working as expected.

The word "red" in English has only one form, although there are different forms of it in Polish, based on: gender, plurality and case:

Non-plural:

```
|              | masculine  | feminine  | neuter     |
|--------------|------------|-----------|------------|
| Nominative   | czerwony   | czerwona  | czerwone   |
| Genitive     | czerwonego | czerwonej | czerwonego |
| Dative       | czerwonemu | czerwonej | czerwonemu |
| Accusative   | czerwony   | czerwoną  | czerwone   |
| Instrumental | czerwonym  | czerwoną  | czerwonym  |
| Locative     | czerwonym  | czerwonej | czerwonym  |
| Vocative     | czerwony   | czerwona  | czerwone   |
```

Plural (neuter is the same as feminine):

```
|              | masculine  | feminine   |
|--------------|------------|------------|
| Nominative   | czerwoni   | czerwone   |
| Genitive     | czerwonych | czerwonych |
| Dative       | czerwonym  | czerwonym  |
| Accusative   | czerwonych | czerwone   |
| Instrumental | czerwonymi | czerwonymi |
| Locative     | czerwonych | czerwonych |
| Vocative     | czerwoni   | czerwone   |
```

As you can see there are in total 12 unique forms of "red" in Polish: 'czerwony', 'czerwonym', 'czerwonego', 'czerwonemu', 'czerwona', 'czerwoną', 'czerwonej', 'czerwone', 'czerwoni', 'czerwonymi', 'czerwonych', 'czerwonym'

What I'd expect from Google App Engine stemmer is to treat all of them as being the same (as being "red"). Let's test it by adding endpoint to the App Engine app, which does as follows:

```
    def test_me():
        forms = {'czerwony', 'czerwonym', 'czerwonego', 'czerwonemu',
                     'czerwona', 'czerwoną', 'czerwonej',
                     'czerwone', 'czerwoni', 'czerwonymi', 'czerwonych',
                     'czerwonym'}

        # turn each form into document and insert to index
        index = search.Index(name=str(uuid.uuid4()))
        index.put([search.Document(language='pl',
                                   fields=[
                                       search.TextField(name='color', value=form,  language='pl')
                                   ])
                   for form in forms])

        missing = {}
        for form in forms:
            # find out what forms can we match to 'form' using ~ stemming operator
            results = index.search(query="~" + form).results
            matching_forms = set([doc.field('color').value for doc in results])

            # and see which we missed
            missing[form] = list(forms - matching_forms)

        return json.dumps(missing)
```

It turns out there's bunch of items, which were not matched correctly:

```
"czerwonym": [
  "czerwona",
  "czerwoną",
  "czerwoni",
  "czerwonych",
  "czerwonej",
  "czerwonymi",
  "czerwonemu"
],
"czerwonemu": [
  "czerwona",
  "czerwoną",
  "czerwone",
  "czerwoni",
  "czerwonych",
  "czerwonej",
  "czerwonego",
  "czerwony",
  "czerwonym",
  "czerwonymi"
],
...
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or maybe I have wrong expectations for GAE stemmer?

Please, note that there's a open-source polish stemmer (https://github.com/morfologik/morfologik-stemming), which handles all 12 forms without any problems. This leads me to believe that my expectations for GAE stemmer are not outrageous.